# google_sign_in signinSilently gets APIException PlatformException(sign_in_required, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 4: 4: , null)

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I make Flutter project and use google_sign_in plugin.
As a title, I always get APIException and can't resolve the problem.

error code is below

```
I/flutter ( 9868): Error Message Silently: PlatformException(sign_in_required, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 4: 4: , null)
```

What I do is that

・Make Firebase Project.

・Make a binding Firebase project to application.

・put appropriate application id (com.companyname.appname).

・put appropriate SHA1 key and SHA256 key.

・set google.services.json to project/app folder.

・import google_sign_in in dart script.

・write this code below

```
final GoogleSignIn gSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();

  void initState(){
    super.initState();

    gSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((gSigninAccount){
      controlSignIn(gSigninAccount);
    },onError: (gError){
      print("Error Message: " + gError.toString());
    });

    gSignIn.signInSilently(suppressErrors: false).then((gSignInAccount){
      controlSignIn(gSignInAccount);
    }).catchError((gError){
      print("Error Message Silently: " + gError.toString());
    });
  }
```

・Go to console.developers.google.com and go to OAuth confirmation screen.

・set an application name.

・set the icon.

・set support email.

・set homepage link.

・set privacy policy link.

・set Terms of service link.

・Go to console.firebase.google.com Authenthication and set confirmation provider and enabled to Google.

Finally, I do the Run code in my Flutter.And I always get the error.

What shall I do?

Please tell me.

This is "flutter doctor -v " below.

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.778], locale ja-JP)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.9 at C:\flutter
    • Framework revision f139b11009 (5 weeks ago), 2020-03-30 13:57:30 -0700
    • Engine revision af51afceb8
    • Dart version 2.7.2


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\---\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\---\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = C:\Users\---\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 45.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[√] VS Code (version 1.44.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\---\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.9.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • S1 • MS3GLP6711406222 • android-arm64 • Android 8.1.0 (API 27)

• No issues found!
```

my app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "3g"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.vyseart1.buddiesgram"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.2.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

my project/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: plz share your gradle files too.

Comment: Thanks to your comment, I edited the post.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Interesting that the PlatformException was thrown only in the Visual Studio, in Android Studio everything works great, and PlatformException was catched the way it should be(but i don't want to go back to AS :) ). I tried to catch the exception in different ways in Visual Studio, but unsuccessfully.

Here is my simple workaround:

```
await auth.googleSignIn.isSignedIn().then((isSignedIn) async {
  // TODO: Implement onError
  if (isSignedIn) {
    await auth.googleSignIn
        .signInSilently()
        .then((value) => user = value, onError: print);
  }
});
```

Before calling signInSilently() method we check that user is signed in, else we don't call this method.

I hope it will help.

**UPD.**

After 1 minute that i post this answer, i found the answer why Visual Studio doesn't wont to catch that PlatformException. The answer is very simple(facepalm):

[Uncaught Exceptions checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCcdw.png)

Just uncheck the "Uncaught Exceptions" checkbox in VS.

Comment: I can't find this option within VS code. How do you get there?

Comment: Open the debug tab(left vertical menu). In bottom left(near "Manage" button) you will see the breakpoints section.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with my android application build.
All you need to do is:

1. Add Project support Email to to your google authentication in firebase console if not done.
2. To Authenticating Your Client Generate SHA-1.

Certain Google Play services (such as Google Sign-in and App Invites) require you to provide the SHA-1 of your signing certificate so we can create an OAuth2 client and API key for your app. To get your SHA-1, follow the instructions to use Keytool or Gradle's Signing Report.

To get the debug certificate fingerprint type this command in terminal:

keytool -list -v 
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%.android\debug.keystore

After this it ask for a Password then type **android** as password and press enter.

This will give result like this:

> Task :app:signingReport
> Variant: debug
> Config: debug
> Store: ~/.android/debug.keystore
> Alias: AndroidDebugKey
> MD5: A5:88:41:04:8D:06:71:6D:FE:33:76:87:AC:AD:19:23
> SHA1: A7:89:E5:05:C8:17:A1:22:EA:90:6E:A6:EA:A3:D4:8B:3A:30:AB:18
> SHA-256: 05:A2:2C:35:EE:F2:51:23:72:4D:72:67:A5:6C:8C:58:22:2A:00:D6:DB:F6:45:D5:C1:82:D2:80:A4:69:A8:FE
> Valid until: Wednesday, August 10, 2044

Now Run the app again. Hope it will resolve the problem.